# How to count the number of of TRUE statements in a dataframe, conditioned that the previous element is also TRUE in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, counting

I have the following dummy data:

```
data <- data.frame(c("FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE"))
```

What I would like to achieve from this data is to count the following things:

1. n_00: the number of times "FALSE" occurred given that the previous element was "FALSE"
2. n_01: the number of times "TRUE" occurred given that previous element was "FALSE"
3. n_10: the number of times "FALSE" occurred given that the previous element was "TRUE"
4. n_11: the number of times "TRUE" occurred given that previous element was "FALSE"

Therefore the resulting numbers that the dummy data should give are:

1. n_00= 2
2. n_01= 2
3. n_10= 2
4. n_11= 2

If have seen and tried to adapt approaches which have been used for similar questions involving runs or counting consecutive arguments, but without success.

In essence what I am trying to do is count the number of elements that fulfill a condition based on the previous element.

If anyone knows a page, could propose a function or loop, that would be very much appreciated as I would like to do this with a larger amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing a simple loop over your vector to count the types of pairs?

```r
x <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)

count_chunks <- function(x) {
  out <- NULL
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    out <- c(out, paste(x[i-1], x[i]))
  }
  table(out)
}

count_chunks(x)
#> out
#> FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE FALSE   TRUE TRUE 
#>           2           2           2           2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this loop has been very helpful! I have tried it out with some more data (around 100) and checked it manually. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! There are many good answers in this thread. Please pick your favorite and "Accept" the solution officially.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `table` to compare the values to the lagged values:

```r
table(previous = data[[1]][-1], current = data[[1]][-nrow(data)])
#>         current
#> previous FALSE TRUE
#>    FALSE     2    2
#>    TRUE      2    2
```

Or if you want to get fancy:

```r
as.data.frame(table(previous = data[[1]][-1], current = data[[1]][-nrow(data)]))
#>   previous current value
#> 1    FALSE   FALSE     2
#> 2     TRUE   FALSE     2
#> 3    FALSE    TRUE     2
#> 4     TRUE    TRUE     2
```

Comment: Thanks also for this one, unfortunately I believe that this code here outputs something else than the other two examples. It counts more TRUE/TRUE observations than are actually present and less TRUE/FALSE and FALSE/TRUE. This could be down to the fact that the lag approach where the two vectors are then added together, does not take into account the order/way in a state of TRUE was achieved.

Comment: @Erich it outputs 2 for each - shown in the value column. This is exactly what you show in your expected output. You don’t need a loop to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your data, a loop approach might get slow. Here is a `dplyr` approach. Probably not as fast as using `table()`.

```
data <- data.frame( var = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE"))
data$var <- as.logical(data$var)
data %>% 
   mutate(lag = lag(var)) %>%
   group_by(var, lag) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(lag)) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) %>%
   mutate(label = paste("n_", as.numeric(var), as.numeric(lag), sep ="")) %>%
   select(label, count)
```

Comment: Thank you also very much for this one, it also manages to output the correct numbers I am looking for!